# NGINX reverse proxy - https://my.org/SERVICE<-> http://192.168.0.x/ possible?

Tags: webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

Let's say **`Service1` **is wordpress, nextcloud, some DMS or other nice stuff in a private network.
**`Service1`** is installed on NGINX at `http://localip:1234**/**`

The url to access `service1` has to be `https://my.org/**service1**`

Nothing special I thought. But after hours of trial and error I am asking myself if it is even possible to forward /service1 to / ?!

(I had success when service1 was operating at `http://localip:1234/**service1**`)

Details:
https://my.org resolves to my router, which forwards 443 to NGINX.
NGINX is dockerized behind the router on its own ip in the private network.

When I try to reverse proxy `https://my.org/service1` to `http://localip:1234` service1 seems broken.
I managed to get some http response from service1 but some elements and links were broken.

Comment: In general that should be possible, _unless_ that proxied server handles references in such manner, that the proxy logic is unable to handle them. For example absolute URLs assembled on the client side which point to the original URL, not to the proxy.

Comment: You will have to be more specific in your question: what is your current implementation of rewriting rules (including the context of the front facing service and what specific requests do not work when your proxy implementation? What does "broken" actually mean, specifically? A timeout? An http status? Another strange thing happening?

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late!

In the meantime I found out that it's at least very tricky to to this with NGINX. Instead of proxy a service to a different url it's much easier to make a subdomain handeling the request and proxy it to this destination.

Example:
Access the service at https://service1.domain.org
NGINX uses proxy_pass to http://seriveip:1234

I'll add some config example later.